# MySQL return based on two columns

Tags: mysql

I've got the following table

```
user_id | extra_id | email         | status
1       | 111111   | asd@asd.com   | 1
2       | 222222   | asd2@asd.com  | 2
3       | 333333   | asd3@asd.com  | 1
4       | 444444   | asd4@asd.com  | 2
5       | 222222   | asd5@asd.com  | 1
```

I'm trying to return all the users that got status = 1 (active users) and they don't have same extra_id with status = 2 (previously disabled)

So the table above should return

```
user_id | extra_id | email         | status
1       | 111111   | asd@asd.com   | 1
3       | 333333   | asd3@asd.com  | 1
```

Comment: Do a self join then select from there. Or a grouping by and a group concat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `not exists` you can check if there is another row with the same `extra_id` and `status = 2`:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t
where t.status = 1
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where extra_id = t.extra_id and status = 2
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wdzq2FPzoePwmXLmdyc7p3/0).
Results:

```
| user_id | extra_id | email        | status |
| ------- | -------- | ------------ | ------ |
| 1       | 111111   | asd@asd.com  | 1      |
| 3       | 333333   | asd3@asd.com | 1      |
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this with a left join antipattern, that ensures that no other record exists with the same `extra_id` and `status = 2`.

```
select t.*
from mytable t
left join mytable t1
    on  t1.extra_id = t.extra_id
    and t1.status = 2
where 
    t.status = 1
    t1.extra_id is null
```

Or, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions: a window `max()` can tell you if the same `extra_id` has another record with `status = 2`.

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        max(status = 2) over(partition by extra_id) has_status_2
    from mytable t
) t
where status = 1 and has_status_2 = 0
```